# Firebase remove orphan data from deleted data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Let's say i have two data like this:

**Posts**

```
"posts": {
    "postid_xx1": {
        "title": "Lorem ipsum"
    },
    "postid_xx2": {
        "title": "Amet laboris"
    },
    "postid_xx3": {
        "title": "Sit quis incididunt"
    }
}
```

**Users**

```
"users": {
    "userid_xx1": {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "posts": {
            "postid_xx1": true,
            "postid_xx3": true
        }
    },
    "userid_xx1": {
        "name": "Jane Doe,
        "posts": {
            "postid_xx2": true
        }
    }
}
```

How to remove `postid_xx1` from `users`, when i remove it from `posts`  ?.

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic data removal feature with Firebase Realtime Database.  You'll have to write code to do this yourself.  As the database is "NoSQL", it doesn't manage the relationships of the data you put into it.  You have to manage those relationships yourself.

You could write it on the client with two calls to remove() ([see the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#delete_data)):

```
firebase.database().ref(`posts/postid_xx1`).remove();
firebase.database().ref(`users/userid_xx1/posts/postid_xx1`).remove();
```

Or you could use Cloud Functions to write a trigger that automatically searches for and deletes matching nodes under `users` when a node is deleted from `posts`.